# align row based on one of its childs in flutter

Tags: flutter

suppose I have a `Row` with 2 items - `ElevatedButton` and `IconButton`.
if I just center the Row (`Center` widget or `MainAxisAlignment.center`), then it will center the row to the screen's center based on the row - see pic (1).
but what if i want to center the row to the screen's center based on the elevatedButton? how can i do that? see pic (2).

[image]

also, in case the row is the first element of a column and the second element is another elevatedButton (red in the new pic), how can i align it to the button (blue) that is inside the row?

[image]

i can achieve it manually but i want it responsive and i wonder if there is a way to do what i want easily